# Topological Manofold is Hausdorf, Second Countable, Locally Homeomorphic to $R^n$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Hier is a result from Topology and Differential Geometry:

A topological manifold is a topological space such that the three conditions are met:

- Hausdorff
- second countable, and
- covered by charts homeomorphic to open subsets in $R^n, \,\,n\in N$.

Statement: None of the three conditions follows from the remaning two. In other words, none of the conditions is dispensible. I can take two of the conditions as holding and eventually suceed in proving analytically the necessity of the third one. What I need is examples which demonstrate that two of the three conditions are not enough in order for a topological space to get the stracture of a topological manifold.

Can somebody show such examples ? Many thanks.

Comment: It may help to notice that the three conditions are equivalent to the third one plus either metrizable or Haussdorf and countable at infinity. I say this because I personally don't like to work with the second countable axiom.  For an example of a topological space satisfying the two first points but not the third one, consider $\{x=0\}\cup\{y=0\}$  with the induced topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Why is the third condition not met ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hausdorf, second countable, not locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$:

- $\mathbb Q$.

Hausdorf, not second countable, locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$:

- The disjoint union of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb R$.

Not Hausdorf, second countable, locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$:

- [The line with two origins](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/the-line-with-two-origins/). As a set, this space is $\mathbb R\cup\{0^*\}$, where $0^*$ is some object not in $\mathbb R$. The open sets consist of all the (usual) open sets in $\mathbb R$, along with those of the form $U\setminus \{0\}\cup \{0^*\}$ and $U\cup\{0^*\}$, where $U$ is any (usual) open subset of $\mathbb R$ containing $0$.